# Install WinUSB without coinstaller

Tags: windows, installation, driver, winusb

I have an application which uses a WinUSB driver to communicate with a device. The application installer preinstalls the device driver, which has a standard WinUSB inf file which includes the WinUSB coinstaller for Windows XP (which doesn't come with WinUSB).

If the user plugs in the device before running the application, everything is fine: the driver is installed, the coinstaller installs WinUSB, and the application runs.

If the user attempts to run the application before plugging in the device, WinUSB is not yet installed and the application refuse to run (because it's linked to winusb.dll).

I'm sure I saw something about an installer for WinUSB which can be run from the application installer without needing the coinstaller, but I can't find it now.

Is such an installer available? Alternatively is there some way that I can force the coinstaller to run from the application installer?